how to destroy a screen after navigating from it in StackNavigator?
I have Navigation structure like this
Profile Screen
Settings Screen
Ad Screen
Now i want to navigate from Settings Screen to Ad Screen , but I want to delete from history Settings Screen.
I tried "NavigationActions.reset(" but I want a simple one solution

You can use :
navigation.replace("AdScreen")

replace
Replaces the current screen with a new screen in the stack. The method accepts following arguments:

name - string - Name of the route to push onto the stack.

params - object - Screen params to pass to the destination route.


https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#replace
